# How is memory handled when destroying DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, memory-management

If I have `click` event listener on many dynamically created elements, will they use the memory when `remove()` is called by `removeEventListner` is not?

Say I have some code like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
  var $btn = $('<button class="my_button">');
  $('body').append($btn);
  $btn.click(function(){ /* ... */ })
}

$('.my_button').remove();
```

Will the event handlers still use memory? Do I have to call `removeEventListner` if I want to make sure there's no memory leak risk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory held by that element will be released when it is removed from the DOM and destroyed. This is handled by the browser, so although there in theory *shouldn't* be any memory leaks you are at the mercy of the garbage collector.

That being said there's a *much better* approach you can use here. Create a **single** delegated event handler on a parent element of all the buttons. Then you have one event handler instance which works for all button elements. This will save memory and mean you don't need to worry about the specifics of any garbage collection when removing elements from the DOM. Try this:

```
$('#buttonContainer').on('click', '.my_button', function() {
  // button click action here...
});
```